# Netcat script to send an email when output file have a string

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I'm trying to do a sh script to netcat an IP and to send an email when a the port is not answering.

So far I have this but altought the script is working and the output file in filled in, but I receive the mail is empty. I debug it by writing something with vi in the output file and I do get the email with what I've written.

Here's the script:

```
netcat -z -v -w x.x.x.x 23 > /path/resultt.txt 2>&1
if grep -q "timed out" /path/resultt.txt ;
then
    ssmtp email@gmail.com < /path/resultt.txt
else
    echo
fi
```

I think it has something to do with doing `2>&1`

Comment: Not sure what version of netcat you are using but some version have an option -o to output communication to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `2>&1` or "send stderr to the same place as stdout" should not be a problem. In cases where the last argument is a number, I like to make sure my redirects have the fd number on them. But, yours does work without it.

I'm using a public telnet based service for this demo. It should work for anyone, but as with all things free, it may not be around forever.

```
$ nc telnetmyip.com 23 > /tmp/out 2>&1

$ cat /tmp/out
{


"comment": "##     Your IP Address is 96.67.120.126 (59742)     ##",


"family": "ipv4",
"ip": "96.67.120.126",
"port": "59742",
"protocol": "telnet",
"version": "v1.1.0",
"website": "https://github.com/packetsar/checkmyip"
}
```

So, that is working exactly as intended.

Now, you say **"but I receive the mail is empty"**. According to your code, an email is only sent if "timed out" is **present in the file**. So, the only way for an empty email to be sent is if you are not giving the *correct file* to `ssmtp` the *correct way*.

You may want to consider doing it like the example at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSMTP#Sending_email

```
# only do this once
$ cat > header.txt <<'EOF'
To:email@gmail.com
From:youraccount@gmail.com
Subject: telnet resulted in a timeout

Hello, admin. I hope this doesn't ruin your day.

The command `netcat -z -v -w x.x.x.x 23 > /path/resultt.txt` resulted in this:
EOF

$ cat header.txt /path/resultt.txt | sendmail -t
```

I hope that helps. In closing I'll repeat: The only way for an empty email to be sent is if you are not giving the *correct file* to `ssmtp` the *correct way*. (Assuming that you have manually confirmed that `ssmtp` works in this environment.)